# Distance between subject and verb in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> “R” denotes “Repeat” and to be distinguished from a letter, is in uppercase.

Should it be

> “R” denotes “Repeat” and to be distinguished from a letter, **it** is in uppercase.

Are they grammatical?

Comment: R, which denotes "Repeat", is in uppercase to distinguish it from ....

Comment: @TRomano thank you, but is my first sentence or the second one ungrammatical?

Comment: You asked about distance, not grammar, and tagged with "sentence-structure".

Comment: It is borderline ungrammatical.  To be distinguishable...or, as Mark H. wrote, and as I wrote above, "to distinguish it..."

Comment: @TRomano I refined the question, however I thought sentence-structure tag implies the grammatical structure of a sentence

Comment: @MarkHubbard you mean both of them are grammatical? I mean could I write either of them?

Comment: @Ahmad, the main problem with both sentences is the usage of passive-voice **distinguished**. It simply does not mean what you want to say. Here are two definitions 1.  "used to describe a respected and admired person, or their work" 2. "used to describe a person, especially an older person, who looks formal, stylish, or wise".  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distinguished. As everybody suggests, use "to distinguish it" or "to make it distinguishable"

Answer (score 4):

The first is very nearly grammatical.  A well-placed comma is all it is lacking and a minor rewording makes it much cleaner.

> “R” denotes “Repeat” and, to distinguish it from a letter, is in uppercase.

You could also, as @TRomano suggested, rewrite it:

> R, which denotes "Repeat", is in uppercase to distinguish it from a letter.

or

> R denotes "Repeat" and is in uppercase to distinguish it from a letter.

Answer (score 0):

It is ungrammatical.

Consider this ungrammatical sentence:

> The text, *to be discerned*, is set in a larger font.

The grammatical versions would be:

> The text, *to be discernible*, is set in a larger font.
>
> So it *can be discerned*, the text is set in a larger font.
>
> The text, *for it to be discerned*, is set in a larger font.

We take action to ensure that the text can be read.

> The text, to be readable, is set in a larger font.
>
> <sup>ungrammatical</sup> The text, to be read, is set in a larger font.

The text is set in a larger font to be readable.

*The text is set in a larger font to be read.

Comment: Explain the downvote.  This is a fine point of grammar and the use of the passive and adjectives formed from it. Just marking this answer down does nothing to clarify anything.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: I think people are going to disagree or agree with this depending on how their ear accepts or rejects "to be read" and similar as the semantic equivalent of "capable of being {past-participled}".